# Ramda, check(filter) if array of strings contains substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter, substring

For example I have an array:

```
let data = [ 'abc', 'dfgx', 'dfgxabc', 'xyzz' ]
```

And test substring:

```
const searchStr = 'abc'
```

I need another array that contains any matched values from `data` array.

```
let result = ['abc', 'dfgxabc']
```

In my task I getting a string from keyboard input, it can contain at least 3 characters and more. So it something like live search.

I'm trying to use Ramda:

```
const data = [ 'abc', 'dfg', 'xyz' ]

const searchStr = 'abc'

const filtered = R.filter(R.match(new RegExp(searchStr, 'i')), data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with native js with the help of [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
const data = [ 'abc', 'dfgx', 'dfgxabc', 'xyzz' ];

const searchStr = 'abc';

const filtered = data.filter(s => new RegExp(searchStr, 'ig').test(s));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of answering the question directly,

```js
const data = [ 'abc', 'dfgx', 'dfgxabc', 'xyzz' ];

const findABC = filter(test(/abc/));

findABC(data)
```

is the equivalent using Ramda. Take a look in the [REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%20%27abc%27%2C%20%27dfgx%27%2C%20%27dfgxabc%27%2C%20%27xyzz%27%20%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20findABC%20%3D%20filter%28test%28%2Fabc%2F%29%29%3B%0A%0AfindABC%28data%29).